# Зачем указывать имя параметра в прототипах?

Tags: c++

[image]
Не совсем понял,зачем следует указывать имя передаваемых параметров в функцию?

Comment: Можете не указывать. Делайте объявления вроде `void glTextureView(GLuint, GLenum, GLuint, GLenum, GLuint, GLuint, GLuint, GLuint);` - ясно и понятно. А в С раньше было еще круче - параметры можно было не писать, или даже вообще функции не объявлять, а сразу использовать.

Comment: Не подскажете, откуда это взято? Просто фраза в достаточной степени вырвана из контекста, хотелось бы посмотреть более полный вариант, о чем говорилось до этого. А так - имена параметров стоит указывать для себя и других читателей кода, чтобы самому не запутаться, что и в какой последовательности передается в функцию...

Comment: Harry, Шилдт c++ 4-е издание, полный справочник

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, речь о том, что компилятор может при выводе сообщения об ошибке несоответствия типов указать имя параметра, который задан неправильно, для удобства исправления ошибки. Это, впрочем, не реализовано в Visual C++ (VS 2017), хотя реализовано в GCC. Возьмем такой ошибочный код:

```
fread(nullptr,"Hello, world",0,nullptr);
```

Вывод Visual C++:

```
error C2664: "size_t fread(void *,size_t,size_t,FILE *)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 2 из "const char [13]" в "size_t"
```

Указан только номер параметра (хотя в прототипе есть имена).

Вывод GCC:

```
main.cpp:15:19: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'size_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-fpermissive]
   15 |     fread(nullptr,"Hello, world",0,nullptr);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   |
      |                   const char*
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/cstdio:42,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:43,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:6493,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/string:55,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/ios:42,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:709:53: note:   initializing argument 2 of 'size_t fread(void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*)'
  709 | extern size_t fread (void *__restrict __ptr, size_t __size,
      |                                              ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

Здесь в последней строке указано имя параметра.

Кроме того, наличие имен параметров полезно для всплывающих подсказок в IDE или для генераторов документации. Так что да, правильно написано, что рекомендуется их указывать.